# Laravel 5.3: Session cookie is still valid after logout

Tags: php, authentication, cookies, laravel-5

This is an experiment on  fresh laravel 5.3 project( default authentication) basic auth flow  works perfectly

**step-A :Obtain the Laravel session cookie**

Open the auth url in normal browser window, After the successfull login i can see the laravel session cookie( ie  `laravel_session` ) in browser cookies section i just copied that value

Application State:Logged in

**step-B: Obtain the authentication using the same session cookie in `incognito` browser window**

1. opened the `http://localhost/finde/public/login` in incognito window which is the login URL for the application in this I've added the Laravel_session cookie  that's obtained from **step-A** via browser console.
2. Now i am able to access the `http://localhost/finde/public/home` URL with the session cookie obtained from **step-A**.

Application state:Logged in

Just go back to  **step-A** application state and logged out from the application so the session cookie is now invalid?.
But when i come back to `http://localhost/finde/public/home`   URL in the incognito window and refreshed it. Oops, its still accessible

But  why this session cookie is still valid ??

Comment: Never solved let me try it